# Facebook Application Troubleshoot

Tags: facebook

My Application is not loading. When I debugged it, I got the following error:

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:site_url.

Please Help. Thank You

Comment: Can you post some code or a link to your page please

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the og:site_url meta tag?

Comment: Where to remove that? I am a real novice. Sorry if I ask stupid questions.

Comment: I cannot find anywhere where there is this og:site_url.

Comment: I tried adding these meta tags, but still got the same problem